# Как сделать подобный эффект?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно сделать подобный эффект, как [здесь](http://faq.mvideo.ru/). При перемещении мыши блок двигается и в блоке видно картинку без прозрачности.

Comment: А почему вы имея рабочий пример не распотрошите его код?

Comment: Наверное потому, что уже посмотрел, и не понял, как реализовано.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, ну так задайте _конкретный_ вопрос по коду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует блок `#cover` с фоном затемненное [изображение](http://faq.mvideo.ru/img/fade_bg_small.jpg)

Сверху лежит небольшой блок с красной рамкой `#small-mask`, у него меняются координаты в зависимости от активности меню. Этот блок имеет css свойство `overflow:hidden`, которое говорит, что все что выходит за пределы этого блока - не видно.

Внутри лежит [картинка без затемнения](http://faq.mvideo.ru/img/clear_bg_small.jpg) , у которой меняются координаты так же, как и у блока `#small-mask`, только со знаком минус.

Получается что в маленьком окне блока `#small-mask` мы видим незатемненную картинку, которая отпозиционированна нужным образом.

Иллюстрация кода, который нас интересует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

п.с. забавно, есть [оригинал изображения](http://faq.mvideo.ru/img/bg.png) 7960x4931

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже по своему написал, в белом прямоугольнике меняю background-position-x и -y