# Как сделать эффект освещения фона при наведении курсора?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

[image: Пример]

С помощью чего можно воплотить эту идею? Имеется ввиду CSS, SVG, JPG (фон) становится видимой при наведении курсора на SVG (png) элемент. 
В данном случае "Лампочка" отдельный html элемент, который является ссылкой. Важный момент - лампочек может быть несколько.

Comment: Попробуйте покрутить маски(http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css). На фон картинку, а блок поверх солидно черный. Придется сильно повозится, но это будет самый гибкий и удобный вариант для вас.

Comment: почему бы просто черный фон не заменить на фон картинки ?

Comment: Насчёт масок думаю хорошая идея! Спасибо! Единственно хочется решить момент как сделать подмену координат фона родительского блока при наведении на вложенный див-ссылку в него. Думаю многим полезен будет этот ход. Можно сделать чтобы ряд иконок (ссылок) освещали одно изображение, а одна иконка подставляла иное изображение. Это если вдруг нужно каждой ссылке свою картинку по тематике.

Comment: У масок есть минус, работают не на всех браузерах.

Comment: Есть маски,  которые везде работают.

Comment: @Telion, объясните или покажите, пожалуйста, частичный пример с масками для данного случая. Просто не совсем представляю каким образом достичь работающего варианта в большинстве браузеров.

Comment: @Agestor Вы не знаете как изменять [SVG маски](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613156/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-css?rq=1) динамичсеки?

Comment: Вопрос заключается в работе на большинстве браузеров. Понятно, что SVG не работают на многих старых с определенными приемами.

Comment: Можно PNG с прозрачностью накладывать и фон показывать

Comment: SVG маски рулят https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/BjRVew/ – [отсюда](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/)

Comment: Виды масок https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью box-shadow и Javascript. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdQbQB

При просмотре обязательно нажать **"На всю страницу"** для правильного отображения эффекта освещения.

```js
$(".bulb").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light:has(>.active)').addClass('shadow');
  $('#outer').addClass('picture');
});

$(".bulb").mouseout(function() {
  $('#outer').removeClass('picture');
  $('.shadow').removeClass('shadow');
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#outer, body{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

#outer, .light {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.bulb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2000px black, inset 0 0 120px 120px black;
}

.light {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}

.picture {
  background: url(https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/946/images/story_full_width/forests-why-matter_63516847.jpg?1345534028);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">

  <div class="light">
    <div class="bulb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="light">
    <div class="bulb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="light">
    <div class="bulb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При просмотре обязательно нажать **"На всю страницу"** для правильного отображения эффекта освещения.

Comment: Благодарю! Но не совсем подходящий вариант. Он даёт подмену фона при наведении (эффект размытия света делается в фотошопе). Минус в том, что если лампочек будет 4, то для каждой нужно отдельный фон, в итоге имеем страницу с четырьмя тяжелыми картинками (фонами) под каждый элемент.

Comment: @Agestor вы хотите, чтобы фон через темноту поглядывал? И несколько лампочек освещали разве участки?

Comment: Да, лампочки освещали разные участки фона.

Comment: Можно box-shadow задавать при наведении на лампочку. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992451/multiple-transparent-circles-using-only-css-cutouts

Comment: Дело в том, box-shadow он лишь создаёт эффект наложением цвета. То есть в данном случае он никак не осветит картинку. Вообще насколько я понимаю, что возможно нужного эффекта возможно добиться только наложением дополнительных изображений, что является неудачным вариантом. Но пока в поисках решений.

Comment: @Agestor Вы неправы, `box-shadow` затемняет все пространство, кроме определенной области.

Comment: @Agestor Сделал чтобы лампочки освещали разные участки фона

Comment: Хех, прикольно, но крайне не гибко..

Comment: @Telion почему не гибко?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. @Alex78191, напишите пожалуйста, еще раз ваш предыдущий ответ отдельно, не успел сохранить. По логике он будет очень полезен, в случае если нужно сделать фон разный, то код позволит вложенному диву двигать фон родителя при наведении. А как можно увеличить площадь освещения? Увеличиваю 120px и перестаёт работать эффект...

Comment: @Agestor Предыдущий ответ доступен в истории изменений. Чтобы увеличить площадь освещения нужно увеличить размеры у класса `.light`.

Comment: Благодарю! Я отмечу ваш вариант как правильный сегодня, единственно не очень люблю использовать jquery для подобных вещей потому, что начинаются мелькания на странице при её открытии, но судя по вашему коду jquery, картинка с затемнением подгружается только после наведения. В этом плане более удачно мне кажется сделать фоновую картинку-карту с освещенными пятнами и черным участком для неактивного состояния. Таким образом картинка будет сразу загружаться вместе со страницей. И вот тут поможет jquery, когда вложенная иконка будет менять фон родителя (её координаты).

Answer (score 3):

Немножко поиграться с PS и вообще можно карту из таких ховеров сделать. Ну типа большой див position: relative; ,a внутри куча позиционных. А это так пример.

```css
.img a{
display:block;
height:300px;
width:300px;
background-image:url(http://savepic.ru/14038389.png);
}
.img a:hover{
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
height:300px;
width:300px;
background-image:url(http://savepic.ru/14026101.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="img"><a></a></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Скажите, пожалуйста, как этом метод с картой называется? Ответ правильный в вашем комментарии про карты. Вопрос каким образом сделать привязку общего вона и нескольких "лампочек" которые будут активировать положение фона.

Comment: Большой див position:relative с исходным фоном;  в нем несколько мелких div position: absolute c hover фоном и нужными координатами.

Comment: Метод никак не называется. Почесал репу - сработала смекалка. :)

Comment: Было бы хорошо увидеть реализацию подмены фона (координат) при наведении на иконку (лампочку). Просто на данный момент ответ ховер на весь фон с его подменой.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Вставлю как новый ответ.

Comment: Смотрите в самом низу

Comment: Я думаю автору нужен вариант через маски. Только масками можно будет сделать это действительно гибко и чисто.

Comment: С масками честно говоря не понимаю как сделать гибко, получается будет фон (затемнен фильтром) и маска для каждого блока с ссылкой?

Answer (score 1):

Запустите в браузере - картинки я не масштабировал, а потому здесь они тупо смотрятся

```css
.all{
display:block;
position:relative;
margin: 10% auto ;
height:50vh;
width:80vw;
border:2px solid red;
}
.img:nth-child(1){
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:20px;
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-image:url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/sun1.png);
}
.img:nth-child(1):hover{
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/sun2.png);
}
.img:nth-child(2){
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:20px;
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-image:url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/sun1.png);
}
.img:nth-child(2):hover{
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/sun2.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
   <div class="img"><a></a></div>
   <div class="img"><a></a></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ну или запустить на всю страницу. Красоту не наводил. Надеюсь мысль ясна.

Comment: Тут получается тот же вариант, только с двумя картинками. Важный момент: есть фон, координаты указывают на черное пустое пятно, и есть ряд иконок, они отдельные html элементы, которые работают как ссылки. И вот тут не ясен момент как сделать, чтобы при наведении только на иконку менялся общий фон.

Comment: то есть чтобы при наведении на один див, hover срабатывал у другого дива?

Comment: вы пишите пока мысли - присоединюсь через несколько часов.

Comment: Получается, что так. Я так понимаю есть общий блок для всего этого дела с фоном черным. В нём дивы которые будут являться контейнерами для ховер изображений. Понятно, что их придётся сделать местами друг на друге потому, что свет будет затрагивать большую область вокруг лампочки. А в этом диве будет ещё один див, который будет являться ссылкой и иметь изображение в виде лампочки. Вот тут и нужно сделать, чтобы при наведении на эту ссылку (в рамках лампочки) менялся фон.

Comment: То что вы сейчас описали, ответ предоставил вам @Alex78191

Comment: Наткнулся на вариант, похожий на то, что нужно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455546/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82 Но не понятно как там идёт привязка, еа сайте М-видео из ссылки не вижу JS кода для этого. Разве нельзя сделать без js, чтобы фон родителя менял значения взаимодействуя с вложенным элементом и hover?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59049/discussion-between-qwerty-wasd-and-agestor).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ajaxBtn").click(function(){ 
var inputText = $("#testText").val(); 
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "index.php", 
    data: "testAjax="+inputText, 
    dataType: "html", 
    success: function(html){ 
      alert(html); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```